# Is this java generic method?

Tags: java, list, generics, methods

```
public Box<T>{

    private T t;

    public void setBox(T t){

         this.t = t;

    }

    public List<T> toList(){

         List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
         list.add(t);

         return list;
    }
}
```

In this simple code is this `toList()` method generic or not?

Thank you...

Comment: Yes, it's a generic method

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html for more.

Comment: You know the term. *Look it up*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, your `toList` is not a generic method.

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), Java SE 8 edition, [Section 8.4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4) says:

> A method is generic if it declares one or more type variables.

So a generic method has type parameters of its own, but your `toList` only uses the type parameters of the class. Hence it is not a generic method.

This is also explained in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) linked to in the comment by Lutz Horn. The section on [generic methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) says:

> Just like type declarations, method declarations can be generic—that is, parameterized by one or more type parameters.

This confirms that a method is generic if it has type parameters of its own.

Here is an example for a generic method:

```
public static <T> List<T> boxToList(Box<T> box) {
  return box.toList()
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, at last someone who reads the question before answering

Comment: On this official Oracle Java Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html, there is an error when it says: // Generic methods
    public void setKey(K key) { this.key = key; }                                                                    Am I correct?
    public void setValue(V value) { this.value = value; }
    public K getKey()   { return key; }
    public V getValue() { return value; }
}

Comment: @momi: Good question. I guess this is an error, yes.

Comment: Well that was the source of my confusion. Anyway, thank you a lot. Cheers